# SQL Server 2016 stretch database - namespace error

Tags: sql-server

I'm using my MSDN and using the 'adventureworks' db (running SQL Server 2016) and running the task to enable a stretch database but running into an error.  I've logged into Azure with my MSDN account and have setup a few VM's etc. so appears my account works.   From my workstation I go to setup the stretch database with my MSDN azure credentials but getting this error:

> Provisioning of Azure Sql Server stretchserver-XXXXX--adventurewor-20160720-143153189 in resource group stretchgroup-spodev150697-sql2016-westus2 failed.
>   Details : {"error":{"code":"MissingSubscriptionRegistration","message":"The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.Sql'."}}

Any thoughts on what steps I need to take to get this registered to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same thing happening to me and my students during a SQL Server 2016 hands-on lab a couple of months ago. It is a weird error that shouldn't happen (it's definitely a bug that you should report).

However, there's a workaround: create an Azure SQL Database manually, then delete it. From that moment on, you will no longer receive the error message.

Comment: Still a bug, and your solution still works!  (and was in a MOC lab!)